# How do I create a filter of a field using another table relationship in a Symfony form?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

What I need to achieve is this: I have a two entities that are related in a one to many fashion: Offer and Product, when the user wants to create an offer, they have to also select a product. That part is done, now the user wants me to add another field (Product Categories which has a one to many relationship with Product), it should a select field, in order to filter the products in the form.

How could I achieve this? I'm using Doctrine.

Edit:

Here is my .orm.yml file

Dayscript\AdminBundle\Entity\Promocion:

```
type: entity
table: promocion
indexes:
    id_producto_regalo:
        columns:
            - id_producto_regalo
id:
    id:
        type: integer
        nullable: false
        unsigned: false
        comment: ''
        id: true
        generator:
            strategy: IDENTITY
fields:
    nombre:
        type: string
        nullable: false
        length: 50
        fixed: false
        comment: ''
    descripcion:
        type: text
        nullable: false
        length: null
        fixed: false
        comment: ''
    tipo:
        type: string
        nullable: false
        length: 15
        fixed: false
        comment: ''
    valor:
        type: float
        nullable: true
        precision: 10
        scale: 0
        comment: ''
    codigo:
        type: string
        nullable: false
        length: 50
        fixed: false
        comment: ''
    url_imagen:
        type: text
        nullable: false
        length: null
        fixed: false
        comment: ''
manyToOne:
    idProductoRegalo:
        targetEntity: Producto
        cascade: {  }
        mappedBy: null
        inversedBy: null
        joinColumns:
            id_producto_regalo:
                referencedColumnName: id
        orphanRemoval: false
lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

Here's a screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2l3y.jpg

The idea is that before choosing the product, there should be another drop down list so the person can filter the products by category before choosing a product.

Comment: can you clarify how a user begins to make an offer?  Are you saying the user interacts with a form that is related to an offer entity and right now they type in an offer and select a product from a choice menu?  To expand that, the user would not first select a category, then go through the same process?  Maybe just add a filter in your twig file to select products by category and leave the rest of the form unchanged.  Please post the entity and form code.

Comment: Just updated the post with a screenshot and the .orm.yml